# Why am I getting 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.' from this code snippet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

So I copy-pasted the brief code snippet

```
public ActionResult Run()
{
    string apiKey = "ABCD-1234";
    string value = "http://www.google.com"; // a url starting with http or an HTML string

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        // Build the conversion options 
        NameValueCollection options = new NameValueCollection();
        options.Add("apikey", apiKey);
        options.Add("value", value);

        // Call the API convert to a PDF
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(client.UploadValues("http://api.html2pdfrocket.com/pdf", options));

        // Make the file a downloadable attachment - comment this out to show it directly inside
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myfilename.pdf");

        // Return the file as a PDF
        return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

from http://www.html2pdfrocket.com/convert-csharp-to-pdf into my web application and am getting a 401 error with a stack trace like

> [WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized.]    System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(Uri address,
>   String method, NameValueCollection data) +490
>   System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(String address, NameValueCollection
>   data) +35    Survey.Controllers.AnswersController.Run() +163
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +14

I tried adding in `client = UseDefaultCredentials = true;`, to no avail.

Any other ideas I can try?

Comment: Have you tried defining proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read this [documentation](http://html2pdfwebservice.com/documentation)

> it's saying in API Authentication Section In case you don't have an
> account yet you can sign up for our 14-day free trial. To authenticate
> against our web service you're required to use your API key and
> username. These can be found on your profile page and dashboard.

Comment: html2pdfwebservice.com is not the same as html2pdfrocket. I know because I own HTML2PDF Web Service :-).